# How to set up localhost4200

Tags: localhost

Hello guys I’m really new to coding and I did a little bit of coding with a guy I use to know. I remember when ever he wanted to see the changes he made to his “test” website he would use localhost4200, can someone help explain to me how this works and how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

"localhost" is just another name for this computer, also commonly referred to as 127.0.0.1. The 4200 is the port that the test website server he was running on that computer was using.

There's a bunch of different ways to host a server on your computer that runs a test website. You can run your own IIS (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323972/how-to-set-up-your-first-iis-web-site) or code your own server using something like Node.js and Visual Studio 2017.